# Send select values to URL pages

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a select menu of drop downs that I am trying to add URL links to. However the drop downs are not as simple as select one and go to the URL.

Firstly I don't want the user to go straight to the URL on select. Instead they need to be able to select the value and then click the "Submit" button below. The button should then take them to the relevant selected URL.

Secondly, depending on the value selected you will either go to the URL or you will be presented with a second drop down. So for example the first menu has 5 values. Values 1 to 4 will take the user to different URLs. However value 5 will present the user with a second menu. Then once they select a value from this menu they will then be taken to that URL.

I have set the form up on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CreativeDSG/67us7n86/) but I am struggling to work out how to get the values into URLs and also how to only send the user to the URL when they click the Submit button.

HTML:

```
<div id="select-1" class="form-group">
    <label>Select menu 1</label>
    <select id="select-1" name="level-1">
        <option value="default" disabled selected class="default">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="select-2" class="form-group">
    <label>Select menu 2</label>
    <select name="level-2">
        <option value="default" disabled selected class="default">Please select</option>
        <option value="sub1">Sub 1</option>
        <option value="sub2">Sub 2</option>
        <option value="sub3">Sub 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-active">Submit</button>
```

jQuery:

```
// First off, lets disable the "Submit" button and hide the additional select menu.
$('#submit').removeClass('btn-active').addClass('btn-disabled');
$('#select-2').hide();

// If values 1-4 are selected then enable the "Submit" btn and keep the second select menu hidden.
// If value 5 is selected then keep the "Submit" btn disabled and display the second select menu. 
$('#select-1 select').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '5') {
        // Keep the submit btn disabled.
        $('#submit').removeClass('btn-active').addClass('btn-disabled');
        // Show the second select menu
        $('#select-2').show();
    } else {
        // Activate the submit btn.
        $('#submit').removeClass('btn-disabled').addClass('btn-active');
        // Keep the second select menu hidden
        $('#select-2').hide();
    };
});

// Once a value has been selected on the second select menu then activate the "Submit" btn.
$('#select-2 select').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() != 'option:[value="default"]') {
        $('#submit').removeClass('btn-disabled').addClass('btn-active');
    }
});
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have twice id="select-1" that's a mistake.

For your problem you could do that :

HTML

```
<div id="select-1" class="form-group">
    <label>Select menu 1</label>
    <select id="level-1" name="level-1">
        <option value="default" disabled selected class="default">Please select</option>
        <option value="link1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="link2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="link3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="link4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="link5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="select-2" class="form-group">
    <label>Select menu 2</label>
    <select id="level-2" name="level-2">
        <option value="default" disabled selected class="default">Please select</option>
        <option value="sub1">Sub 1</option>
        <option value="sub2">Sub 2</option>
        <option value="sub3">Sub 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button id="submit" class="btn btn-active">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
// First off, lets disable the "Submit" button and hide the additional select menu.
$('#submit').removeClass('btn-active').addClass('btn-disabled');
$('#select-2').hide();

// If values 1-4 are selected then enable the "Submit" btn and keep the second select menu hidden.
// If value 5 is selected then keep the "Submit" btn disabled and display the second select menu. 
$('#select-1 select').change(function() {
    if($("#level-1")[0].selectedIndex == '5') {
        // Keep the submit btn disabled.
        $('#submit').removeClass('btn-active').addClass('btn-disabled');
        // Show the second select menu
        $('#select-2').show();
    } else {
        // Activate the submit btn.
        $('#submit').removeClass('btn-disabled').addClass('btn-active');
        // Keep the second select menu hidden
        $('#select-2').hide();
    };

});

// Once a value has been selected on the second select menu then activate the "Submit" btn.
$('#select-2 select').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() != 'option:[value="default"]') {
        $('#submit').removeClass('btn-disabled').addClass('btn-active');
    }
});

$('#submit').click(function(){
    var link;
    if($("#level-1")[0].selectedIndex == 5){
        link = $('#level-2').val();
    }else{
        link = $('#level-1').val();
    }
    window.location.href = link;   
});
```

Just put the link you want in the value attribute.

Comment: This works great, thanks. Just one question, is there an option where you could make some of the links open in a blank window?

Comment: Also instead of using `selectedIndex` could you also use the selected value? Just thinking of easy maintenance in the event additional items get added or the ordering change.

Comment: to open the links in a blank windows just use window.open(
  link,
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);

Answer (score 0):

you mean adding something like this?

```
$("#submit").on('click',function(){
    var option1 = $("#select-1 :selected").val();
    var option2 = $("#select-2 :selected").val();
    window.location.href= window.location.href+="?option1="+option1+"&option2="            +option2;

});
```